# Get the shop base country in a third party WooCommerce plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, country

I am creating a plugin for Woocommerce and I need to block it from being installed when store country is not in US (for example)

```
function init(){
    if (in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' )))) {

        $shop_country = WC()->countries->get_base_country(); // FAIL: Call to a member function get_base_country() on null 

        if ($shop_country !== 'US') {
            add_action( 'admin_notices', 'show_error' ); return;
        }

        /**
         * The core plugin class that is used to define internationalization,
         * admin-specific hooks, and public-facing site hooks.
         */

        init_my_plugin();
    }
    else{
        add_action( 'admin_notices', 'show_error' );
    }
}
add_action('plugins_loaded','init');

function show_error(){
    ?>
    <div class="error">
        <p><?php _e( 'This plugin requires WooCommerce in order to work.', 'plugin' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

In my init function, I try to get the store country (got ERROR here) and if it is not US, I show error and not let them install the plugin. However, I got error: Call to a member function get_base_country() on null.

I believe that my function is called when the Woocommerce object is not ready. Could you show me the right hook to achieve that? I want to get the store location to check if my plugin supports that country

Note: what do I mean shop/store country? I refer to the country field that is in the Woocommerce setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the shop base country you, don't need to use WC_Countries Class, so replace:

```
$shop_country = WC()->countries->get_base_country();
```

By:

```
$shop_country = wc_get_base_location()['country'];
```

Or by this too:

```
$shop_location = get_option( 'woocommerce_default_country' ); 
$shop_location = explode(':', $shop_location);
$shop_country  = reset($shop_location);
```

As the shop base location is stored in `wp_options` table.